# Specflow changing UTF encoding of auto generated code behind C# file when feature file text changes

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, notepad++, specflow

I came across an encoding issue when I upgraded from a direct DLL reference to Specflow version 2.2.0 - to a NuGet reference of version 3.1.7.4.

Now when I change text in my feature file, Specflow changes the encoding of its associated code behind C# file from UTF-8-BOM to UTF-8. As we have a script in our Cruise Control build verifying that the correct encoding (UTF-8-BOM) is being used, we are getting warnings when this script is ran.

The fix is easy, you just open the .cs C# file in Notepad++, click the encoding menu and change it back from "Encode in UTF-8" to "Encode in UTF-8-BOM" and save the file.

This is obviously easily forgotten and annoying to remember!

Has anybody any thought on how to stop Specflow changing the encoding on every feature file change or even why it is doing this?

Comment: Why don't you just report the issue to [SpecFlow](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues)?

Comment: Fair enough. I've opened the following issue: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1871

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by György Kőszeg, I reported the issue on github and SabotageAndi responded today with the following, so this issue should be fixed in a future release.

> I made some research and found out that UTF-8 + BOM is really the default encoding for C#- files. That was a surprise for me, I always thought it was only UTF-8.
>
> So I am happy to review and accept a PR that fixes this. Should not be a big change. I think only the File.WriteAllText calls in https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/blob/master/SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation/CodeBehindWriter.cs has to be changed.

UPDATE

The issue has now been fixed and should be available in a release in the very near future. https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/pull/1933